# Windows integrated authentication Azure AD and WinForms

Tags: winforms, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal, jwt

We have a very large Winforms project and we need to use SSO with AAD to make API calls to an external API service.

I'm using MSAL and the methods:

```
app.AcquireTokenSilent
app.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth
```

However, I get the error:

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: Integrated Windows Auth is not supported for managed users. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-iwa for details.
>
> at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.IntegratedWindowsAuthRequest

using the method:

```
app.AcquireTokenInteractive
```

The application shows a prompt for the user to select what account wants to use (the prompt shows connected to windows) and I don't need to enter the password, right after I click the user it sings in and gets the token.

After I get the token and it is saved using `PublicClientApp.UserTokenCache` the next logins even if the token is expired I don't need to select the account the user sing in automatically.

I want to avoid that first prompt.

I have tried 2 options (none worked):

1. A user created in Windows AD and then synced to AAD
2. A user created in AAD and then created in Windows AD

Additional information:

- Treat application as a public client is marked yes in the app registration.
  ​
- I used the same app registration with a web application (SPA) and using Microsoft Edge I can login without the user interaction, it signs in automatically

The problem is only with the Winforms application

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this turned out to be a bug in the library in the newest version is solved.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1737

solved in 4.20 version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: HI, I'm sitting on this right now, can you give me some more info?

Comment: sure!     https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1737   

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-iwa-v2

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD MSAL docs don't cover it, but for Windows Integrated Auth to work with MSAL, either of the following needs to be available and set up in the hydrid AAD setup. Mere AAD Connect setup wont work.

1. [Azure Active Directory Seamless Single Sign-On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso)
2. [Federation with ADFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-whatis)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, @Kalyan-Krishna. I have checked this seamless sign-on configuration   >> Seamless single sign-on Enabled 1 domain, I guess there is a bug in the MSAL library as it works when the user clicks on its name for the very first time and the consecutive logins work like a charm even if the previous token is expired, I didn't try with ADFS, as is not the company's path.